# Login to parse with facebook in a phonegap app

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying hard to login to parse after the user is connected to facebook (directly login to parse is done correctly but not with facebook). The problem is that neither the success nor the error callback block is called, so I don't know how to track down the issue in such case.

My relevant code is the following:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
               appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',// my facebook app ID
    });

    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {

    success: function(_user) {
               if (!_user.existed()) {
                       alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
               } else {
                       alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
               }
    },

    error: function(error1, error2){
             alert("Unable to create/login to as Facebook user");
        }
    });// finish login
};// window.fbAsyncInit


    (function(d, s, id){
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?